# Polymorphic associations referencing user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, polymorphism

I've set up projects, tasks, and subtasks, all of wich are commentable. I have created comments model and connected the models but don't know how to properly validate for user id and how to test model code using Rpsec and Factory Girl. I am also using Devise.

**Comments Migration**

```
  1 class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  2   def change               
  3     create_table :comments do |t|   
  4       t.references :user, :null => false
  5       t.text :comment,  :null => false,
  6                         :limit => 500                   
  7       t.references :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  8         # upper line is a shortcut for this
  9         # t.integer :commentable_id     
 10         # t.string :commentable_type    
 11       t.timestamps         
 12     end                    
 13     add_index :comments, :user_id   
 14     add_index :comments, :commentable_id
 15   end
 16 end
```

**Comment Model**

```
1 class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  2         
  3   # RELATIONSHIPS   
  4   belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  5   belongs_to :user
  6   # VALIDATIONS            
  7   validates :user, :presence => true
      validates :commentable, :presence => true
  8   validates :comment, :presence => true,
  9                       :length => { :maximum => 500 }  
 10 
 11   # ATTRIBUTE ASSIGNMENT   
 12   attr_accessible :comment 
 13   
 14 end
```

**User Model**

```
  1 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  2         
  3   # RELATIONSHIPS   
  4   has_many :synapses, :dependent => :destroy
  5   has_many :projects, :through => :synapses
  6 
  7   has_many :vesicles, :dependent => :destroy
  8   has_many :tasks, :through => :vesicles
  9 
 10   has_many :subvesicles, :dependent => :destroy
 11   has_many :subtasks, :through => :subvesicles, :dependent => :nullify
 12   
 13   has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
 14   
 15   # VALIDATIONS
 16   validates :name,  :presence => true,
 17                     :uniqueness => true             
 18 
 19   # ATTRIBUTE ASSIGNMENT   
 20   attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
 21 
 22   # DEVISE MODULES         
 23   # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 24   # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
 25   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
 26          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
 27          :confirmable      
 28 
 29 end
```

**Comment Factory**

```
105   factory :comment do
106     comment "This is some generic comment with some generic content"
107   end
```

**Comment Model Specs**

```
  1 require 'spec_helper'      
  2         
  3 describe Comment do
  4 
  5   it 'Should create new comment' do
  6     FactoryGirl.build(:comment).should be_valid
  7   end                      
  8 
  9   it 'Should respond to method provided by polymorphism to find its parent' do
 10     FactoryGirl.build(:comment).should respond_to(:commentable)
 11   end                      
 12 
 13 end
```

This 1st test currently fails with error message saying **undefined method `user' for #Comment:0xa88c354>**. But if I pass in user id like this...

```
FactoryGirl.build(:comment, :user => confirmed_user).should be_valid
```

Than I should have user id set up as mass assignable attribute, and I don't want that (figure that some users might mess with that attribute and change it). **How to test and validate this properly?** Also, this is my 1st time doing polymorphic, so if you see anything silly, let me know.

Edit. I have now done this as one answer suggested. Unfortunately, it returns the same error.

```
  5   it 'Should create new comment' do
  6     confirmed_user = FactoryGirl.build(:confirmed_user)
  7     FactoryGirl.build(:comment, :commentable => confirmed_user).should be_valid 
  8   end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace:

```
:user => confirmed_user
```

with:

```
:commentable => confirmed_user
```

**UPD:**

```
validates :user, :presence => true
```

also has to be:

```
validates :commentable, :presence => true
```

Comment: I have tried and it returned the same error message. I have updated the question with the code I entered.

Comment: ok, this passed the test! but I don't understand how this model code validates for user_id to be present?

Comment: man, I am so sorry, forgot to put belongs_to user in comments model. I do want to have that. I have edited the question. Now when I run this test it says > expected valid? to return true, got false

Comment: Now you have to add both `:user` and `:commentable` to your `build(..)` call - they both are required.

Answer (score 1):

The model Comment should have:

```
belongs_to :user
```